# Gyroscope doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gyroscope

after multiple search, I can not find the answer, so I appeal to your knowledge. Since the last Chrome update on android, I can not use my gyroscope on virtual tours online anymore. My gyro includes my up and down motion but not right and left. Firefox is ok... Do you have more information?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

It's a Chrome bug introduced in v65, as it appears from here [bugs.chromium.org/](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=DeviceOrientation%20&sort=-modified&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified). I'm using Chrome Beta to keep testing my work that uses the DeviceOrientation API since it works there. This also means that the bug will be fixed once the stable Chrome reaches v66 publicly.